# How to start browser in incognito mode by default?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, browser, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have a samsung galaxy tab 2 10" running Android 4.0.4. Is there a way for the default browser to automatically start up in incognito mode? Or, is there an alternative browser that can do it?

Comment: Don't even try Firefox for Android for this, it cannot start in private mode and no extensions or special URLs can enable it (also not `about:privatebrowsing`). But the feature is being worked on, see [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1088772) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/3u8o0k/default_to_private_tab_in_android/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the default browser being able to -- but searching the Playstore for [incognito browser](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=incognito+browser&c=apps) yielded a bunch of promising results:

- **[InBrowser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nu.tommie.inbrowser)** promises to be *a fully featured incognito/private browsing experience for Android 1.6 and upwards including Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich.* Looks like it knows nothing else than "incognito browsing" (i.e. no other mode). Rated 4.3 stars with 2000+ votes, it sounds very promising.
- **[INCOgnito Private Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SL.InCoBrowser)** seems to be comparable. Again a 4.3 star rating, but not yet 100 votes (too new, I guess)
- **[Frost Lite - Private Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.crowbar.beaverlite)** is a third example I want to mention here: rated 4.4 stars at about 1,500 votes it seems to be more feature-rich than aforementioned browsers (e.g. offers tabbed browsing).

For more details, just follow the links. For more examples, use the first link to my Playstore search results.

I would like very much to offer you a solution for the pre-installed browser as well -- but unfortunately, I a) do not know any, and b) I think it unlikely. Of course I love to learn better -- so anybody, please correct me if I'm wrong with my assumption :)

Answer (score 5):

You might want as well to set an incognito tab as homepage, so that everytime you will open your default android browser, an incognito tab will open.

Here' how:

1. Open stock/android's default browser.
2. Open a new incognito tab
3. Goto settings > General
4. Set home page > Current page.

Now you have an incognito page as your default page (and it will autonatically open, when you open your browser).

Comment: To clarify, this applies only to the default browser shipped with Android 4.0 on a Galaxy Tab 2 10", whatever that is. If you install for example Firefox and make it the default browser, there will not be the required setting …

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - Naked Browser is the only browser for Android you can trust as truly private with each new browsing session.

Setting the Android Browser home page to the current page on an incognito browser does not actually start incognito mode. It just opens the static page that launches with incognito mode. You can tell because when you switch to the address bar, there is no incognito man logo. Same when you open the tabs view.

As per private browsing, none of those browsers give the authentic incognito mode features. Test by doing a Google search then exit the browser. Relaunch and navigate back to Google. When you focus on the search bar, if your previous search appears in purple in a drop down list, then obviously not all information is being destroyed between browsing sessions.

My method:

Although not advertised as a private browser, Naked Browser has advanced privacy features that essentially allow you to start in incognito mode. This is the only browser I tried (I spent hours testing different "private" browsers) that actually started each session from scratch when the delete history on exit option was selected. You can also use a custom URL for searching from the address bar, so by default all inquiries in my set up go through https://encrypted.google.com.

Bonuses:

You can disable JavaScript and cookies as well. If you buy the pro version you can whitelist individual sites to allow cookies/JavaScript (it's like a simplified NoScript extension!). There are also other detailed settings like custom actions for long pressing links that can be combined with gestures. For example, in my settings, long pressed links open in new tabs in the background, but if I follow through with a side swipe gesture, I will switch to the tab. I can also double tap and swipe up/down to reach the bottom/top of the page (useful!). A two finger swipe down will open a new tab and swiping left/right at the bottom will switch through background tabs.

Anyway! All the basic privacy options are there in the free version, but I'm so blown away (still, almost a year later) that I'm gushing about how great Naked Browser (Pro) is. Not the prettiest browser but far and away the best (and fastest?)!